# Resolution Issue on install

Tags: system-installation, display, resolution

[image]

I'm unable to install elementary OS due to this resolution issue, does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: Does "Try elementary OS" work fine?

Comment: Not a good sign that no one has answered this. I'm having the same problem now trying to install elementary OS on a Lenovo Yoga Pro 2.

Comment: You can try to try XD Elementaryos from a live USB or CD and then install it from their. It works for my! I have a HDMI TV and old Acer desktop.

Comment: It looks like your install is not recognizing the correct display resolution for your computer. If you have the ability, I would say try to use a different display port (I.E. DVI-VGA or HDMI-DVI) while in a live environment to make sure that your monitor is sending the correct info to the computer. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start the elementary OS live mode from the installation medium so that you can check *System Settings*/*Displays* to fix this problem.

Even if you cannot fix the resolution you can move the installation window if you drag it with the windows key held down.